# Error when starting program: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported

Tags: c++, linux, gtk, gtk3

In my program, I am getting the above error. There are couple of questions related to this error but in all the ones I looked, `ldd` shows people that they are using both `gtk-3` and `gtk-2`. In my case, here is the output of `ldd`

```
$ ldd ./myExe | grep gtk
libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f1cdef89000)
```

As you can see, my program links only against `GTK3`. So, what could be the reason I am getting this error then?

Comment: are you using any other libraries?

Comment: I am using many libs, but as far as I know, `lld` shows chain of dependencies. If one of the libs were to depend on `GTK2`, I think it should have been shown on the above command, am I wrong?

Comment: it doesn't show statically linked libraries

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/gtk/blob/158a2b0e1e8d582bc041acc7fe323922747d7787/gtk/gtkmodules.c#L596). Is it possible thay you have a widget called GtkProgress?

Comment: Is it possible that `opencv2/xfeatures2d` is using `GTK2`? Including that file seems to be the problem. Though, I thought `OpenCV 3` and above uses `GTK3`.

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev `nm` shows no symbols named `GtkProgress` or any symbol containing string `gtk`.

Comment: it might be possible, how did you setup your opencv?

Comment: Opencv _can_ be built with gtk2 [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9a8a964b698b00f22229e1bef8f14f3e2f57a980/CMakeLists.txt#L233)

Comment: Probably this is the case, OpenCV is using GTK2. The strange thing is lld is not showing any GTK2. I guess it is statically linked to GTK2. I will rebuild it with full GTK3 support and update the question.